# What means image literal or rather the word literal?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, literals

What means image literal or rather the word literal?

like in Xcode on the top bar there's an option called image literal

Comment: Where in XCode do you see "image literal" mentioned?  A screenshot would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `literal` is a value that is directly represented in the code.

Examples:

```
let i = 3                  // 3 is an Integer Literal
let arr = ["a", "b", "c"]  // ["a", "b", "c"] is an Array Literal
```

Swift has other literals such as Color Literals and Image Literals.  Those are
special compiler directives which directly encode the color or reference to an image.

This allows the Xcode editor to do special things such as show a color literal directly in the code as a color splotch instead of just showing confusing/meaningless floating point numbers.  And it allows you to select the color by double clicking on the color splotch to bring up the standard color picker.

```
// Paste this into Xcode.  The color will be shown directly
let color = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3411764801, green: 0.6235294342, blue: 0.1686274558, alpha: 1)
```

[image: colorLiteral in Playground]

Comment: O I like the #colorLiteral :}